# What should be the Input types for Earth Mover Loss when images are rated in decimals from 0 to 9 (Keras, Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-recognition

I am trying to implement the NIMA Research paper by Google where they rate the image quality. I am using the TID2013 data set. I have 3000 images each one having a score from 0.00 to 9.00

```
df.head()
>>
Image Name          Score
0   I01_01_1.bmp    5.51429
1   i01_01_2.bmp    5.56757
2   i01_01_3.bmp    4.94444
3   i01_01_4.bmp    4.37838
4   i01_01_5.bmp    3.86486
```

I **FOUND** the code for loss function given below

```
def earth_mover_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    cdf_true = K.cumsum(y_true, axis=-1)
    cdf_pred = K.cumsum(y_pred, axis=-1)
    emd = K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(cdf_true - cdf_pred), axis=-1))
    return K.mean(emd)
```

and I wrote the code for model building as:

```
base_model = InceptionResNetV2(input_shape=(W,H, 3),include_top=False,pooling='avg',weights='imagenet')
for layer in base_model.layers: 
    layer.trainable = False

x = Dropout(0.45)(base_model.output)
out = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x) # there are 10 classes

model = Model(base_model.input, out)
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer,loss=earth_mover_loss,)
```

**PROBLEM**:
When I use `ImageDataGenerator` as:

```
gen=ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.15,preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

train = gen.flow_from_dataframe(df,TRAIN_PATH,x_col='Image Name',y_col='Score',subset='training',class_mode='sparse')

val = gen.flow_from_dataframe(df,TRAIN_PATH,x_col='Image Name',y_col='Score',subset='validation',class_mode='sparse')
```

It either gives an error during Training or loss value of `nan`

I have tried a few methods:

1. Creating the scores as `rounded = math.round(score)` and use `class_mode=sparse`
2. Creating the scores as `str(rounded)` and then use `class_mode=categorical`

but I am having error every time.

**PLEASE help me with loading the images using `ImageDataGenerator` about how am I supposed to load the images into this model**.

Model structure should not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following what was introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673551/working-of-the-earth-mover-loss-method-in-keras-and-input-arguments-data-types), I have a couple of ideas about the [NaN gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919818/theano-sqrt-returning-nan-values)...

I think that your loss is nan because the sqrt is computed on a negative number which is not allowed. so there are two possibilities:

- clip the values before applying the sqrt. In this way we clip all the value <= 0, substituting them with a small epsilon

  ```
  def earth_mover_loss(y_true, y_pred):
      cdf_true = K.clip(K.cumsum(y_true, axis=-1), 0,1)
      cdf_pred = K.clip(K.cumsum(y_pred, axis=-1), 0,1)
      emd = K.sqrt(K.maximum(K.mean(K.square(cdf_true - cdf_pred), axis=-1), K.epsilon()))
      return K.mean(emd)
  ```
- exclude the sqrt, in this way the Earth Mover Loss is more similar to a MSE between CDFs

  ```
  def earth_mover_loss(y_true, y_pred):
      cdf_true = K.clip(K.cumsum(y_true, axis=-1), 0,1)
      cdf_pred = K.clip(K.cumsum(y_pred, axis=-1), 0,1)
      emd = K.mean(K.square(cdf_true - cdf_pred), axis=-1)
      return K.mean(emd)
  ```