# Working of the Earth Mover Loss method in Keras and input arguments data types

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I have found a code for the Earth Mover Loss in Keras/Tensrflow. I want to compute the loss for the scores given to images but I can not do it until I get to know the working of the Earth Mover Loss given below. Can someone please describe that what is happening in the code.

The last layer of the model or output layer is like:

```
out = Dense(10,activation='softmax')(x)
```

What should be the input types for this method.I have my `y_labels` in the form of `1.2,4.9` etc etc. I want to use it with Keras/Tensorflow

```
def earth_mover_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    cdf_true = K.cumsum(y_true, axis=-1)
    cdf_pred = K.cumsum(y_pred, axis=-1)
    emd = K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(cdf_true - cdf_pred), axis=-1))
    return K.mean(emd)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can see EML as a sort of RMSE for CDF probability functions

given N classes, all you need is a normalized probability score for each sample. in neural network domains, this is achieved with softmax activation function as output layer

The EML simply compares the CDF of predictions vs realities

In a classification problem with 10 classes, for a single sample, we can have these arrays

y_true = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] # the sample belong to the 4th class

y_pred = [0.1,0,0,0.9,0,0,0,0,0,0] # probabilities output of softmax layer

on them we compute CDFs and get the following scores:

CDF_y_true = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

CDF_y_pred = [0.1,0.1,0.1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

as defined above, the EML compute the RMSE on this CDFs

```
y_true = np.asarray([0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.])
y_pred = np.asarray([0.1,0.,0.,0.9,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.])

cdf_true = K.cumsum(y_true, axis=-1)
cdf_pred = K.cumsum(y_pred, axis=-1)
emd = K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(cdf_true - cdf_pred), axis=-1))
```

In the specific case of NIMA Paper by Google on TID2013, N=10 and the labels are express in the form of float scores. In order to train the network with EML these are the steps to follow:

- digitalize the float scores in 10 intervals
- one-hot encode the labels to get softmax probabilities and minimize EML

at the end of the train, our NN is able to produce, on a given image, a probability score for each class.
we have to transform this score in a mean quality score with a related standard deviation as defined in the paper.
to do this we follow the procedure defined in the paper

bins = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

y_pred = [0.1,0,0,0.9,0,0,0,0,0,0] # probabilities output of softmax layer

mu_score = sum(bins*y_pred) = 1*0.1 + 2*0 + 3*0 + 4*0.9 + ... + 10*0

sigma_score = sum(((bins - mu_score)**2)*y_pred)**0.5

```
bins = np.arange(1,11)
y_pred = np.asarray([0.1,0.,0.,0.9,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.])

mu_score = np.sum(bins*y_pred)
std_score = np.sum(((bins - mu_score)**2)*y_pred)**0.5
```